# Issue with ms access 2000, repeating display of same field in query

Tags: ms-access-2000

I was having an issue with ms access 2000 in which I try to enter the same field in a query multiple times and it only displays the field once. As in if I entered the field with the number being (for example) 8150 multiple times, it would only display it once.
 [image: ms access 2000 query/field issue]

This image shows the query.

I've already checked everything on ms access 2000 to try to resolve this issue but I've come up with nothing suitable.

[image: This image contains the issue I'm having and what I need it to be.]

[image: This image should be self-explanatory]

Comment: Not feeling it...  any chance you can mock up some sample data of 1) what it's doing and 2) what you want it to do?

Comment: I created a picture of exactly what's wrong with it and what I need it to do, I'll update the question to include the new picture.

Comment: Is it possible the results are showing up, but not the way you want them to?  I'm wondering if you are missing a sort.  Two additional requests.  1) can you please send the SQL for the "Dialine Specs Query" -- the raw text, and 2) can you give snapshots of what the Ring and Stones table data looks like for Ring 8150 and 8246.  This should help identify what might be wrong.

Comment: I updated the question again. I really do appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

I know your data set is simplified, but looking at your data, inputs, etc, it appears your query is pulling from a single table and repeating results -- so there is no join consideration.

I think the issue is your DISTINCTROW in the query, which is removing all duplicate values.

If you remove the "DISTINCTROW," I believe it may give you what you are expecting.  In other words, change this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Ring.[Ring Number], Ring.[Mounting Weight]
FROM Ring
```

To this:

```
SELECT Ring.[Ring Number], Ring.[Mounting Weight]
FROM Ring
```

For what it's worth, there may also be some strategies to simplifying how this query is run in the future (less dependence on dialog box prompts), but I know you probably want to address the issue at a hand first, so let me know if this doesn't do it.

-- EDIT --

The removal of `distinct` still applies, but I suddenly see the problem.  The query is depicting the logic as "OR" of multiple values.  Therefore, repeating the value does not mean multiple rows, it just means you've repeated a true condition.

For example, if I have:

```
Fruit     Count
------    ------
Apple     1
Pear      1
Kiwi      3
```

and I say select where Fruit is Apple or Apple or Apple or Apple, the query is still only going to list the first row.  Once the "Or" condition matches true, short-circuiting kicks in, and no other conditions matter.

That does not sound like what you want.

Here's what I think you need to do:

1. Get rid of the prompts within the query
2. Load your options into a separate table -- the repetition can occur here
3. Change your query to perform an inner join on the new table

New table (named "`Selection`" for the sake of example):

```
Entry    Ring Number    Mounting Weight
-----    -----------    ----------------
1        8105           you get the idea...
2        8110
3        8110
4        8110
5        8115
6        8130
7        8130
8        8130
9        8130
10       8150
```

New Query:

```
select
  Ring.[Ring Number], Ring.[Mounting Weight]
from
  Ring
  Inner join Selection on Ring.[Ring Number] = Selection.[Ring Number]
```

This has the added advantage of allowing more (or less) than 10 records

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately the answer still comes out the same, there is no repetition.

Comment: You're right -- it went completely by me the first time.  I'm suggesting an architectural change here, but I think this may be the only way to do what you want.  I don't think it can be accomplished via prompt (although someone is welcome to prove me wrong)

Comment: I have been trying to solve this issue for a while but at this point it seems we both hit a roadblock. If you can come up with something else, please let me know. Thank you for trying.